# powershell script to connect to multiple computers and execute some wsus related commands

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set up a powershell script to automatically connect to multiple client computers that didn't send a report to wsus, and execute some wsus related commands.

I figured out how to get the list of computer that don't send the report anymore. This is the command I used:

```
$ClientsList = Get-WsusComputer -ComputerTargetGroups CLIENT
    -ToLastReportedStatusTime 01/01/2020 | Select-Object FullDomainName
```

But now that I have the clients' list, my problem is that I don't know what commands to use to be able to automatically start an "Enter-PSSession" to every client.

Of course I could manually provide every clients' name to connect to, but I would like to manage this automatically starting from the list I got.

Thank you in advance for any help you will provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it with invoke-command? This foreach connect to each client in you list and execute the code inside the ScriptBlock parameter.

```
ForEach ($Client in $ClientsList)
{
     Try
         {
             Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Client -ScriptBlock {YOUR CODE} -ErrorAction Stop
         }
     Catch
         {
             Add-Content Unavailable-Clients.txt $Client
         }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, I managed to get my script working using invoke-command you suggested.

Comment: Or `invoke-command $ClientsList { 'your code' }` and they will run in parallel.

Comment: Did it. Thank You for your suggestion